# How can I extract data from a list of dicts using graphene's mutation method?

Tags: graphql, flask-graphql

I’m trying to created a list of objects using `graphql mutation`, but have been unsuccessful. I've identified the error, please see code snippets and comment on where the error is propagating.

**Note: I'm using [Graphene](http://graphene-python.org/docs/mutations/) on Flask with Python 2.7**

Here’s an example payload:

```
mutation UserMutation {
    createUser(
        phones: [
            {
                “number”: “609-777-7777”,
                “label”: “home"   
            },
            {
                “number”: “609-777-7778”,
                “label”: “mobile"   
            }
        ]
    )
}
```

On the schema, I have the following:

```
class CreateUser(graphene.Mutation):
    ok = graphene.Boolean()
    ...
    phones = graphene.List(graphene.String())  # this is a list of string but what I need is a list of dicts!
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For having a dict as a Input, you need to use `InputObjectType`. (`InputObjectType`s are like ObjectTypes but just for input data).

This example should work with graphene `1.0`.

```
class PhoneInput(graphene.InputObjectType):
    number = graphene.String()
    label = graphene.String()

class CreateUser(graphene.Mutation):
    class Input:
        phones = graphene.List(PhoneInput)
    ok = graphene.Boolean()

class Mutation(graphene.ObjectType):
    create_user = CreateUser.Field()
```

Comment: Hi Syrus, how to save the phones into db. I use the document code but the database is not affected